# x, y query parameters in Rails search form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, query-string

I have a search form in a Rails app that generates the following HTML

```
<form action="/users" method="get">
  <fieldset>
    Search by name:
    <input class="text" id="query" name="query" type="text" value="" />
  </fieldset>
  <input class="submit" src="/images/buttons/search.png?1296324322" type="image" />
</form>
```

When I submit the form, the url has `x` and `y` query parameters in addition to the `query` one in the form:

```
http://.../users?query=test&x=8&y=21
```

where are these params coming from?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Browsers submit `x` and `y` parameters when you use an image as your submit button. The values signal the position within the image that the user clicked.